# Operator overloading with python outside a class

Tags: python-3.x, class, operator-overloading

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,m1,m2):
        self.m1 = m1
        self.m2 = m2

    def __add__(self, other):
        ''' add takes 2 objects basically objects on RHS and LHS of + say a + b '''
        print("Inside add")
        s3 = A(self.m1+other.m1,self.m2+other.m2)
        return s3

    def disp(self):
        print('{} {}'.format(self.m1,self.m2))

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.m1,self.m2)

def __add__(self,other):
    return self*other

a = 2+5
print(a)
```

Output seen is: 7
Whereas expected is 10 since I am trying to overwrite the implicit add function with multiply operation.
What happens here?
Does operator overloading works only with pytclass?

Comment: Why would you expect ```print(a)``` to output ```10```?   You have ```a = 2+5```.  You're not even using the the ```class A``` and ```def __add___(self,other)``` doesn't mean what you think it means outside of a class.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A:
   def __init__(self,m):
       self.m=m
   def __str__(self):
      return str(self.m)
   #multiply two objects
   def __mul__(self,other):
      t=self.m*other.m
      return A(t)
   #add two objects
   def __add__(self,other):
       t=self.m+other.m
      return A(t)
obj1=A(2)
obj2=A(5)
#calling operator overloading of '*'
print(obj1*obj2)
#calling operator overloading of '+'
print(obj1+obj2)
```

Comment: OP was asking how to overload outside a class. Not inside.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function outside the class and define/redefine the magic operator overload attribute to be that function

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,m1,m2):
        # your code here
        .
        .
        .

    def __add__(self, other):
        .
        .
        .

# code outside class
def f(self, other):  # don't need to use 'self'. can have any name
    return self * other

A.__add__ = f  # redefine addition


a = 2+5
print(a)
```

Note that this won't work for built-in types.